# Decompressing .bz2 files in a directory in python

Tags: python, compression

I would like to decompress a bunch of .bz2 files contained in a folder (where there are also .zst files). What I am doing is the following:

```
 destination_folder = "/destination_folder_path/"

 compressed_files_path="/compressedfiles_folder_path/"

 dirListing = os.listdir(compressed_files_path)

 for file in dirListing:

     if ".bz2" in file:

        unpackedfile = bz2.BZ2File(file)
        data = unpackedfile.read()
        open(destination_folder, 'wb').write(data)
```

But I keep on getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mycode.py", line 34, in <module>
    unpackedfile = bz2.BZ2File(file)
  File ".../miniconda3/lib/python3.9/bz2.py", line 85, in __init__
    self._fp = _builtin_open(filename, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename.bz2'
```

Why do I receive this error?

Comment: `_builtin_open(filename, mode)` in bz2.py expects a full file path here. What are you passing to this function?

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your quick reply! So here I am passing to "open" the full path of the destination folder, which is "destination_folder" defined above, indeed.

Comment: If your bz2 files are in the same directory as the Python script that works with them, you can simply use [`bz2.open("filename.bz2")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html#examples-of-usage). If your `compressed_files_path` and your script directory are not the same, you need to use the full path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You must be sure that all the file paths you are using exist.
It is better to use the full path to the file being opened.

```py
import os
import bz2


# this path must exist
destination_folder = "/full_path_to/folder/"

compressed_files_path = "/full_path_to_other/folder/"

# get list with filenames (strings)
dirListing = os.listdir(compressed_files_path)

for file in dirListing:
    # ^ this is only filename.ext
    if ".bz2" in file:
        
        # concatenation of directory path and filename.bz2
        existing_file_path = os.path.join(compressed_files_path, file)

        # read the file as you want
        unpackedfile = bz2.BZ2File(existing_file_path)
        data = unpackedfile.read()

        new_file_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, file)
        with bz2.open(new_file_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(data)
```

You can also use the shutil module to copy or move files.

[os.path.exists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)

[os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

[shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)

[bz2 examples](https://pymotw.com/3/bz2)

Comment: Great, it worked, thanks a lot! So basically the problem was the path name? This is weird though, as I am sure it was the complete and correct path..Another follow-up question: I am trying to decompress in the same folder also the .zst files in it. Can I simply and naively use this function "zstandard.ZstdDecompressor()" in the same way I used "bz2.BZ2File" or is it more complicated than this? Thanks in advance again for your help!

Comment: In your example code, after reading the data, you are trying to open the folder - `open(destination_folder, 'wb')`. The [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function is used to open a file. It's not entirely clear what exactly you want to do with the data. In my example, I am just saving data from one bz2 file to another bz2 file in a different folder. This works, but if you want a different result, rewrite this part. I can't say anything about zstandard. It looks like it is a third-party library that needs to be installed.